# This series converges or diverges? $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^{3/2}\sin\left(\frac{3}{n^3}\right) $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am studying the convergence of the series: 
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^{3/2}\sin\left(\frac{3}{n^3}\right) $$

I have tried the following: As, $|\sin x|\le 1$ and term of the series are positves we have, 
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^{3/2}\sin\left(\frac{3}{n^3}\right) \le \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty  n^{3/2} =\infty$$

but this estimate  leads neither to convergence nor to the divergence.

What is an elegant to prove the convergence or the divergence of this series? thanks in advance.

Comment: use that $|\sin(x)|\leq |x|$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $|\sin(x)|\le |x|$ and as in your series you are feeding the $\sin$ positive numbers you get

$$\sum_n n^{3/2}\sin\left(\frac{3}{n^3} \right)\le 3\sum_n \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\,, $$

which is known to converge.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{n^{3/2}\sin\frac3{n^3}}{\frac{n^{3/2}}{n^3}}=3\,\frac{\sin\frac3{n^3}}{\frac3{n^3}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}3$$

and thus, by the limit comparison test, our series converges since $\;\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^{3/2}}{n^3}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{3/2}}\;$ converges.

Comment: Can you please take a look to MY answer and kindly explain to me what is wrong, because it looks exactly like your answer. You would do me a great favor because another user is tormenting me since a long time saying that my answers are wrong, even if they are right. Thank you in advance

Comment: @Raffaele It honestly does not look as your answer, and even less "exactly" . Please read my comment under your answer. And sometimes some users here can be tough, specially when trying to correct somebody else's answers, but **in this case** Did's critic is correct.